# Regex dont work like intended

Tags: regex

I'm need help with a regex

```
'#\[quote=(.+);(.+)](.+)\[/quote]#Usi'
```

This works, but it should only work if you use it right, IE

```
[quote=SvenMarklund;53124]kåle på kaffe de varte snörauka å kölblåst borta kamjox så ma lej bivack hela natta﻿[/quote]
```

it wont match this, which is good:

```
[quote=OlleMarklund]jag vill inte ha en pörskans zingo!﻿[/quote]
```

but if you do this in the same post, it "breaks" (see picture)

```
[quote=OlleMarklund]jag vill inte ha en pörskans zingo!﻿[/quote]
[quote=OlleMarklund;23523]jag vill inte ha en pörskans zingo!﻿[/quote]
```

How can I match only if [quote=something;(numbers)]

[image]

Comment: Escape backslash in `[/quote]` ==> `[\/quote]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fixed regex:

```
'~\[quote=([^[\]]+);([^[\]]+)]([^[\]]+)\[\/quote]~si'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV2iE8/4)

You need to capture `OlleMarklund` and `23523` while still inside the opening `[quote]`. To achieve that, you need to restrict the greedy `.+` subpattern and the best way to do it is by using a *negated character class* `[^[\]]` (that matches any character but `[` and `]`).

If you need to match some more tags inside `[quote]`, you need to use something like

```
'~\[quote=([^[\]]+);([^[\]]+)]((?:(?!\[\/quote]).)+)\[\/quote]~si'
```

to only match up to the first `[/quote]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV2iE8/5)). For nested, tags, you'd better use BBCode parser.

Comment: maybe i explained bad, but its [quote=OlleMarklund;23523] i want to match not [quote=OlleMarklund]

Comment: Then remove the `?`: [`\[quote=([^[\]]+);([^[\]]+)]([^[\]]+)\[\/quote]`](https://regex101.com/r/zV2iE8/4)